# Can I cap one of two drain lines under my kitchen sink?

Tags: plumbing, sink, p-trap

My kitchen sink is a double, and I wanted to convert it to a single. However, pretty much every guide I find shows that most doubles use the same p trap, while my sink has a separate p trap and wall entry for each bowl. Is it possible to just cap one of the pipes and only use the other, or do I need to do something else?

[image: under sink image showing each bowl going to its own DWV line into the wall]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is unusual in a kitchen, but not uncommon in a bathroom (I've got 2 separate drain lines going into the wall in my new bathroom).

Yes, you can simply buy a threaded cap for one drain line, screw it on and leave it be.

Run your single bowl drain line through a trap to the other. Use whichever drain is easiest to get the plumbing to and cap off the other.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: If you connect to the left drain, and cap the right, given the water and electric supplies located on the left, you will then have all your utilities on one side and a better open space on the right side that you can use for a two-tier shelf, a pullout, or whatever storage you want.

Comment: Really good point, @jay613! Great catch.

Comment: Also consider that, if you can determine which is the furthest upstream, abandoning that one would allow removal of cap for drain cleaning past the in-service connection, without the hassle of trap disassembly...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can abandon one of those by removing the tubular trap and using a threaded cap at the wall stub.